# Data Cleaning (read, change date format, calculate) in Excel

Tags: excel, date, logic

I tried to find the way from other questions but I am keep getting error message and can't find the right one... So it would be much appreciated if you can help me.
I have a text file and you can download it from link here:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ag44bY-ZJIWUm2N3wxMdOTZctz90

It would be great if you can tell me how to do following steps:

1. Read the data in Excel
2. Change the date format to yyyy-mm-dd h:mm (i.e. 2016-03-14 17:24:55)
3. Amount column means amount of rain. I'd like to know total rain of morning (00:00 - 12:00) and total rain of afternoon (12:00 - 24:00) per each day. The sample that I want can be downloaded here : https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ag44bY-ZJIWUm2Zz-GW9sBtu4ZA7

Many thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am expecting you will be able to import the text data into Excel, if not let me know I will let you know how to do it.
After importing the file in excel in Column F  use the formula =CONCATENATE(MID(B2,5,2),"/",MID(B2,7,2),"/",LEFT(B2,4))
in Column G use the formula
=IF(MID(B2,10,2)+0>13,"Amount of Rain in the afternoon","Amount of Rain in the morning")
Then simply create a Pivot table Put Column F in Rows, Column G in Columns and Column C (Amount) in Sum of Values to get your desired Data
Excel I worked on is https://www.dropbox.com/s/psiovaetou7jpe5/Rain.xlsx?dl=0

Sumil